# QR code with blank spots for manual selection

Tags: qr-code

I want to put a QR code on flyers with specific blank spots which would change the data in a way that the link it refers to changes in a readable way. Like a row of blocks at the bottom that if any of the blocks is colored the id at the end of the url changes.

http://example.com/id/1

```
0101100101
0101011001
0110010101
0110110100
0101101010
0000000001
```

http://example.com/id/2

```
0101100101
0101011001
0110010101
0110110100
0101101010
0000000010
```

And so on. The idea is that someone can use a pen to color the spot and then scan the code to get to the information they are interested in specifically.

I understand with the encoding and error correction this might not be easy if it is possible at all. So is this possible at all?

Comment: QR codes are much more complex than that, it's not so that the URL final part is stored at the bottom row of the squares. You'd probably find there is 1 way only to get a scanable code, and that a minor change in URL changes much more. [some fun here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHTWTyV7VJQ)

Comment: I have tried some python generators to see if I could get some ids that are similar, but adding the whole url part too it the encoded data is just too different to produce anything usable. Since the encoding is known I thought perhaps there is a way to find commonality somewhere for this to work or even just a way to alter the code in any detectable way